# Liquid, изменение кнопок

Tags: javascript, liquid

Не смог разобраться, как правильно навесить изменение кнопок у товара.
При наличии товара в корзине, у кнопки товара должен меняться фон на зеленый. Получилось получить сравнение товара в корзине и коллекции товара. Код ниже:

```
  EventBus.subscribe('update_items:insales:cart', function () {
  let prodId = data.id;
  let item = Cart.order.getItemByID(prodId);
  let btn = document.querySelector('.product-button');
  console.log('ID : ', prodId);
  if (item) {
    console.log(item.id);
    btn.style.background = 'green';
  } else {
    console.log('проверка');
  }
});
```

Меняет цвет только у первой кнопки.
Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то так.

```js
let state = false;

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.a'),
    changeState = document.querySelector('.b');

changeState.addEventListener('click', () => {
    state = !state;
    if(state){
        buttons.forEach(button => button.style.background = 'green')
    } else {
        console.log('null');
        buttons.forEach(button => button.style.background = '')
    }
} );
```

```html
  <div class="container">
            <button class="b">Change</button>
            <button class='a'>Click</button>
            <button class='a'>Click</button>
            <button class='a'>Click</button>
            <button class='a'>Click</button>
            <button class='a'>Click</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, вопрос немного в другом)

Comment: Объясните подробнее, постраюсь помочь)

Comment: Имеется две карточки товаров. Под каждой из них кнопка "купить", мне нужно чтобы скрипт считывал, имеется ли тот, или иной товар в корзине. Если да, то менял кнопку "купить" на "В корзину". 
Такое очень часто можно увидеть на разных сайтах.